# How to encrypt nested folders inside a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to make a program that can encrypt a directory. What I have currently though, can only encrypt files inside the directory and not encrypt the folders nested. An example would be if you wanted to encrypt the "Pictures" folder, it would also encrypt the "Saved Pictures" and "Camera Roll" along with the files inside "Pictures". Any help would be appreciated

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os

'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open('key.key', "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)
'''


def load_key():
    file = open('key.key', 'rb')
    key_ = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key_


key = load_key()
fer = Fernet(key)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\{user}\encrypt_test".format(user=os.getlogin()))
files = os.listdir()
print(files)

for i in range(len(files)):

    with open(files[i], 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    with open(files[i], 'w') as f:
        print(len(data))
        f.write(fer.encrypt(data).decode())
        print('done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking to do is recursively go through a directory to find all files and apply some action to it. The [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) method as you've seen only gives you the entries in the immediate directory. While you could use that method to write a recursive method (e.g. check if a given entry is a directory, if so, run `os.listdir` over it, else encrypt, repeat), it's must easier to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which will handle the recursion down the file tree for you, as well as separating out the files from directories at each level. The one thing to note here is the `files` array that `os.walk` returns is just the names of the files at that level, and so you need to combine it with the `root` value to get the full path.

Rewriting your code to use that renders:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import path

'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open('key.key', "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)
'''


def load_key():
    file = open('key.key', 'rb')
    key_ = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key_


key = load_key()
fer = Fernet(key)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\{user}\encrypt_test".format(user=os.getlogin()))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    print(files)
    for filename in files:
        filepath = path.join(root, filename)

        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            print(len(data))
            f.write(fer.encrypt(data).decode())
            print('done')
```